Reset superuser password in SQL Anywhere
Coming from PostgreSQL, I am new to SQL Anywhere and need to reset the superuser password. In PostgreSQL, I would usually go through the following procedure: I forgot the password I entered during PostgreSQL installation
What are the equivalent steps required to reset the superuser password in SQL Anywhere in case one has access to the SQL Anywhere database file (e.g. example.db)?

Start the Database in Utility Mode
dbsrvXX -f example.db

XX is version for SQLAnywhere
Connect to the database:
dbisql -c "UID=DBA;PWD=sql;ENG=example;DBF=example.db"

DBA and sql are default credential
ALTER USER DBA IDENTIFIED BY 'new_password';

then restart the database and confirm the changes.
